# Where are my Themes in SharePoint Designer _themes folder

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to brand a SharePoint 2007 Site Collection and have created a new theme. I use to see it in the _themes folder of my SharePoint designer.  For reasons unknown to me, I can no longer see any themes in my _themes folder in SharePoint designer.  The only file I now see is themes.inf.  As such, I cannot edit any css files using this tool and would like to have access.  I appreciate suggestions on how to again see the themes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently if your site Theme is not applied to your site then the theme does not show up in SPD. Once I went into Site Settings and Applied my custom theme to the site collection it showed up on SPD.